# 既存Webサービスに Bluesky アカウントでログインできるようにしたい

Tags: webapi

やりたいこと
PHPとJavaScriptで作成された、ログイン機能がある既存Webサービスに、SNSの Bluesky アカウントでもログインできるようにしたい

---

何を取得してどこへアクセスすればよいですか？

Q1.何を取得すればよいですか？
・username と password を取得すれば良い？
・password とは、アプリパスワードのこと？
・user側は、アプリパスワード作成が必須ですか？

Q2.どうやって取得するのですか？
・アプリパスワードはどうやって取得するのですか？
・入力してもらうのですか？
・ボタンクリックしたら連携される、みたいな機能は提供されていませんか？

Q3.どこへアクセスすればよいですか？
アクセス先は [com.atproto.server.createSession](https://docs.bsky.app/docs/api/com-atproto-server-create-session) ですか？

Comment: Twitter類似サービスのことを指しているのなら、ドキュメントは https://docs.bsky.app/ です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google、X、Facebook等が提供しているOAuthのようにそのアカウントでログインしたいと言うことでしょうか？AT ProtocolでのOAuthの実装をどのようにするかどうかは提案(proposal)の状態であり、まだ存在しない(実装していない)ようです。

[proposals/0004-oauth/README.md at main · bluesky-social/proposals · GitHub](https://github.com/bluesky-social/proposals/blob/main/0004-oauth/README.md)

実装されればドキュメントに明記されると思われますが、接続方法はOAuth2.0の仕様に従うと思われます。基本は、Googel等のOAuth2.0でのやり方とそれほど変わらないでしょう。